# How to present this figure with a graph?Or how to create a reinforcement learning envireronment with allowing the agent to rotate and move workstation

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, reinforcement-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L45FV.png)

I am wondering if there is way to present this layout as a graph given that there is node that present just the path?
my second question if it possible to make an environment allow an agent to place workstation to find the optimal configurations by himslef. if it yes can you give me a hint please.

I have tried to present this as a plot but I have no clue how to make it dynamic in which an agent can behave.

Comment: One question at a time, please!

Comment: I am wondering if there is way to present this layout as a graph given that there is node that present just the path?